# Why is my object empty after constructing and returning it?

Tags: php

I tried creating an object in PHP for PHPMailer to be used in development enviroments.

```
class Configuration
    function __construct()
    {
    // creating an object for configuration, setting the configuration options and then returning it.
         return $config = (object) array(
             'DevEnv' => true,                      // DevEnv setting is used to define if PHPMailer should use a dev mail address to send to or not.
             'ReceiverEmail' => 'email@gmail.com',  // Set the develop enviroment email. 
             'ReceiverName' => 'name'              // Set the develop enviroment email name.
         );
    }
}
```

Then I call the class in another controller:

```
protected $configuration;
function __construct()
{
    $this->configuration = new Configuration();
}
function SendInfoMail()
{
            foreach($this->configuration as $config) {
                var_dump($config);
                if ($config->DevEnv == true) {
                    // do stuff
                }else{
                    // do stuff
            }
        }
```

for some reason, it just dumps an empty object. I also tried using

```
  var_dump($config->ReceiverEmail);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors do not work that way. They do not have a return value – http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

`new ClassA` always returns an instance of that class.

Comment: Ah I see, I feel rather stupid now, since I should've known..

Thanks though! I'll mark your answer as a solution!

Answer (score 2):

You have instance of Configuration class. Instead of that, try to add new method let's say "getProperties()".

```
class Configuration
    function getProperties()
    {
    // creating an object for configuration, setting the configuration options and then returning it.
         return $config = (object) array(
             'DevEnv' => true,                      // DevEnv setting is used to define if PHPMailer should use a dev mail address to send to or not.
             'ReceiverEmail' => 'email@gmail.com',  // Set the develop enviroment email. 
             'ReceiverName' => 'name'              // Set the develop enviroment email name.
         );
    }
}
```

So you can call it wherever you want:

```
protected $configuration;
function __construct()
{
    $this->configuration = new Configuration();
}
function SendInfoMail()
{
            foreach($this->configuration->getProperties() as $config) {
                var_dump($config);
                if ($config->DevEnv == true) {
                    // do stuff
                }else{
                    // do stuff
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using constructor incorrectly. See this working example:

```
class Configuration {
    protected $configuration;
    function __construct() {
    // creating an object for configuration, setting the configuration options and then returning it.
         $this->configuration = (object) array(
             'DevEnv' => true,                      // DevEnv setting is used to define if PHPMailer should use a dev mail address to send to or not.
             'ReceiverEmail' => 'email@gmail.com',  // Set the develop enviroment email. 
             'ReceiverName' => 'name'              // Set the develop enviroment email name.
         );
    }
}

class Class2 {
    //protected $configuration;
    function __construct() {
        $this->configuration = new Configuration();
    }

    function SendInfoMail() {

        var_dump($this->configuration);
        foreach($this->configuration as $config) {
            if ($config->DevEnv == true) {
                // do stuff
            }else{
                // do stuff
            }
        }
    }

}


$t = new Class2();

$t->SendInfoMail();
```